# Drop several CSV files in a folder, based values on a column in them, using glob

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, glob

I have hourly temperature and rainfall observations from nearly 2000 stations. Each station has its own csv file which temporally extend from May to August 2022.
First by using the globe, I convert the hourly data to averaged daily and save new csv file named as **"StationName - edited.csv"**.

```
df.head()
Out[5]: 
         date      station      lat       lon   Rain   Temp
0  2022-05-01  72750494999  46.5475 -93.67667  100.0  109.4
1  2022-05-02  72750494999  46.5475 -93.67667   93.0   96.8
2  2022-05-03  72750494999  46.5475 -93.67667   93.0   96.8
3  2022-05-04  72750494999  46.5475 -93.67667  100.0   96.8
4  2022-05-05  72750494999  46.5475 -93.67667   87.0   98.6
```

Next I want to put all these 2000 csv's in a one file using **concat** command. However, some of these csv's (nearly 150) does not have rainfall observation so their **Rain** column in the csv is empty, and manually finding them through 2000 files is vert tedious task.

Can anyone suggest a solution for me to eliminate this csv's files (the one with missing values) from entering the **concat** command, or only used those which have both columns. For example, I got the idea of indicating a **IF** in the code so that if the csv has missing value the code drop this csv from the **concat** command!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Read all the csv if Folder
import glob
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('*.csv'))
# Create an empty dataset
e = pd.DataFrame()

for f in filenames:
    # read the variables
    df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None)

    # I think I should add something here!

    e = pd.concat([e, df], axis=0)
```

Comment: `df['column_name'].describe()[0]` will give you amount of rows column has, - you can place if statement before the `concat` and do not import .csv if amount of non-empty rows is less than X or equals 0

Answer (score 0):

**First a helpful comment:**

`concat` doesn't need to get initialized with `e` and it doesn't need to be in a loop getting run multiple times. Something like the following is a more typical approach:

```
dfs=[]
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    dfs.append(df)
e=pd.concat(dfs,axis=0)
```

**Now a direct answer:**

Using an `if` in the loop checking each `df` will work fine. You can mask each `df` to look for non-null values `df[df['Rain'].notnull()]` and check that there's still something left over `len(df[df['Rain'].notnull()])>0` to confirm that some observations do exist in each file. You should be able to use something like this:

```
dfs=[]
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    if len(df[df['Rain'].notnull()])>0:
        dfs.append(df)
e=pd.concat(dfs,axis=0)
```